# Psycopg2 rowcount for server side cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am querying a Postgres database for a large number of results and want to use server side cursors to stream the results to my client. It looks like when I do this, the `rowcount` attribute of the cursor is now set to `-1` after I execute the query. I'm creating the cursor like so:

`with db.cursor('cursor_name') as cursor:`

Is there a way to find the number of results of my query while streaming results from the database? (I could do a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, but I'd like to avoid that because I'm trying to abstract away the code around the query and that would complicate the API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a server-side cursor, although `cursor.execute()` returns, the query has not necessarily been executed by the server at that point, and so the row count is not available to `psycopg2`. This is consistent with the [DBAPI 2.0 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) which states that `rowcount` should be -1 if the row count of the last operation is indeterminate.

Attempts to coerce it with `cursor.fetchone()`, for example, updates `cursor.rowcount`, but only by the number of items retrieved, so that is not useful. `cursor.fetchall()` will result in `rowcount` being correctly set, however, that performs the full query and transfer of data that you seek to avoid.

A possible workaround that avoids a completely separate query to get the count, and which should give accurate results is:

```
select *, (select count(*) from test) from test;
```

This will result in each row having the table row count appended as the final column. You can then get the table row count using `cursor.fetchone()` and then taking the final column:

```
with db.cursor('cursor_name') as cursor:
    cursor.execute('select *, (select count(*) from test) from test')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    data, count = row[:-1], row[-1]
```

Now `count` will contain the number of rows in the table. You can use `row[:-1]` to refer to the row data.

This might slow down the query because a possibly expensive `SELECT COUNT(*)` will be performed, but once done retrieving the data should be fast.